# Flutter - Call Firebase onMessage method when the app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

The question is same as here [Call onMessage method when the app is in background in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115255/call-onmessage-method-when-the-app-is-in-background-in-flutter) and I am following the thread but since there is no response, I am asking this question again.

I've connected my Flutter app with [Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) and I am receiving notification when my app is in **Foreground** using the [Flutter Local Notifications Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). But I cannot receive any notification when my app is in **Background**

Following is my code:

```
// FIREBASE CONFIGURATION & HANDLING
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    debugPrint("onMessage: $message");
    final notification = message['data']['notification'];

    Map responseBody = convert.jsonDecode(notification);

    _showNotification(
      icon: responseBody['icon'],
      title: responseBody['title'],
      body: responseBody['body'],
    );

    setState(() {});
  },
);


// DISPLAY NOTIFICATION - HEADS UP
Future<void> _showNotification({String icon, String title, String body}) async {
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id',
    'your channel name',
    'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.Max,
    priority: Priority.High,
    ticker: 'ticker',
  );

  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    title,
    body,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
  );
}
```

Can someone please guide me how can I receive notifications when my app is in **Background**

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/808877?

Comment: Yes. But doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved!!**

The issue was with the format of curl calling. As per the instructions given [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#sending-messages)

Changed this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Title",
        "body": "Notification Body",
    },
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
  },
  "to": "YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN"
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "id": "1",
    "status": "done",
  },
  "notification": {
    "body": "Notification Body",
    "title": "Notification Title"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "to": "YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN"
}
```